# Information repeating on subsequent pages

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

Using IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1.7IF8

I am developing a report that should have multiple lists of information on the report page, separated by category headers.  The problem is that "page" will likely span multiple, physical pages on a printed document.  The header for group one shows on every page.  (I suspect that subsequent groups -- like 2 of 3 -- would also appear inappropriately on later pages.)

The lists in my report are not the same, so I can't have a single list with a group (which would, otherwise, solve this problem).  I have developed this using blocks to layout the page.

How can I keep stuff from repeating where it should not?

I have developed [a report using the samples](https://pastebin.com/cz0tv53Z) to demonstrate the problem and provide starting code for anyone who may work on this.  This is a very simple example.  When using this, please realize that the queries in my actual report are not compatible.  They can't be mashed into a single query.

StackOverflow requires me to post the code here, so...

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/15.5/" useStyleVersion="11.6" expressionLocale="en-us">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <page name="Page1">
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                    <pageBody>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                        <contents>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <textItem>
                                        <dataSource>
                                            <staticValue>West</staticValue>
                                        </dataSource>
                                    </textItem>
                                </contents>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;padding-top:2em"/>
                                </style>
                            </block>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <list horizontalPagination="true" refQuery="West" name="List2">
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <sortList>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="First name"/>
                                        </sortList>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                            </block>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <textItem>
                                        <dataSource>
                                            <staticValue>East</staticValue>
                                        </dataSource>
                                    </textItem>
                                </contents>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;padding-top:2em"/>
                                </style>
                            </block>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <list horizontalPagination="true" refQuery="East" name="List1">
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <sortList>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="First name"/>
                                        </sortList>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                            </block>
                        </contents>
                    </pageBody>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_legacyDrillDown" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </page>
            </reportPages>
            <pageSetup>
                <namedPaper name="/configuration/pageDefinition[@name=&apos;Letter&apos;]"/>
            </pageSetup>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2015-11-25T21:38:24.820Z"/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <queries>
        <query name="East">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Province or state">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Province or state]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Last name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[First name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Quantity]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country] in (&apos;Australia&apos;, &apos;Austria&apos;, &apos;Belgium&apos;, &apos;China&apos;, &apos;Denmark&apos;, &apos;Finland&apos;, &apos;France&apos;, &apos;Germany&apos;, &apos;Italy&apos;, &apos;Japan&apos;, &apos;Korea&apos;, &apos;Netherlands&apos;, &apos;Singapore&apos;, &apos;Spain&apos;, &apos;Sweden&apos;, &apos;Switzerland&apos;, &apos;United Kingdom&apos;)</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="West">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Province or state">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Province or state]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Last name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[First name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Quantity]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country] not in (&apos;Australia&apos;, &apos;Austria&apos;, &apos;Belgium&apos;, &apos;China&apos;, &apos;Denmark&apos;, &apos;Finland&apos;, &apos;France&apos;, &apos;Germany&apos;, &apos;Italy&apos;, &apos;Japan&apos;, &apos;Korea&apos;, &apos;Netherlands&apos;, &apos;Singapore&apos;, &apos;Spain&apos;, &apos;Sweden&apos;, &apos;Switzerland&apos;, &apos;United Kingdom&apos;)</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
</report>
```

Also, here is a screen capture showing the problem.

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

IBM Support helped with this one.  There is a known behaviour (I say issue) with the way blocks work on the page.  The solution doesn't use blocks.

1. With the list selected go to ... | Headers & footers | List headers & footers.
2. Check *List page header*.
   Alternative:  If you want the header to show only the first time (not every page) use *Overall header*.
3. "Unlock" the report.
4. Drag the items from the block(s) to the header.
5. Delete the block(s).
6. Format the list header (I assume you don't want a border around it.)

You may need to create singletons to get the page data onto the list.  In my case, I didn't.

Here's what my sample report looks like after these steps:

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/15.5/" useStyleVersion="11.6" expressionLocale="en-us">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <page name="Page1">
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                    <pageBody>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                        <contents>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    
                                </contents>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;padding-top:2em"/>
                                </style>
                            </block>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <list horizontalPagination="true" refQuery="West" name="List2" showColumnTitles="startOfDetails">
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse;border-top-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-bottom-style:none;border-left-style:none"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <sortList>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="First name"/>
                                        </sortList>
                                        <listPageHeader>
                                            <listRows>
                                                <listRow>
                                                    <rowCells>
                                                        <rowCell colSpan="6">
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <staticValue>West</staticValue>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lh"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                                <CSS value="border-top-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-bottom-style:none;border-left-style:none;font-weight:bold"/>
                                                            </style>
                                                        </rowCell>
                                                    </rowCells>
                                                </listRow>
                                            </listRows>
                                        </listPageHeader>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                            </block>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    
                                </contents>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;padding-top:2em"/>
                                </style>
                            </block>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <list horizontalPagination="true" refQuery="East" name="List1" showColumnTitles="startOfDetails">
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <sortList>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Province or state"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                            <sortItem refDataItem="First name"/>
                                        </sortList>
                                        <listPageHeader>
                                            <listRows>
                                                <listRow>
                                                    <rowCells>
                                                        <rowCell colSpan="6">
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <staticValue>East</staticValue>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lh"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                                <CSS value="border-top-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-bottom-style:none;border-left-style:none;font-weight:bold"/>
                                                            </style>
                                                        </rowCell>
                                                    </rowCells>
                                                </listRow>
                                            </listRows>
                                        </listPageHeader>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                            </block>
                        </contents>
                    </pageBody>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_legacyDrillDown" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </page>
            </reportPages>
            <pageSetup>
                <namedPaper name="/configuration/pageDefinition[@name=&apos;Letter&apos;]"/>
            </pageSetup>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2015-11-25T21:38:24.820Z"/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <queries>
        <query name="East">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Province or state">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Province or state]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Last name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[First name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Quantity]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country] in (&apos;Australia&apos;, &apos;Austria&apos;, &apos;Belgium&apos;, &apos;China&apos;, &apos;Denmark&apos;, &apos;Finland&apos;, &apos;France&apos;, &apos;Germany&apos;, &apos;Italy&apos;, &apos;Japan&apos;, &apos;Korea&apos;, &apos;Netherlands&apos;, &apos;Singapore&apos;, &apos;Spain&apos;, &apos;Sweden&apos;, &apos;Switzerland&apos;, &apos;United Kingdom&apos;)</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="West">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Province or state">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Province or state]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Last name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[First name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Quantity]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country] not in (&apos;Australia&apos;, &apos;Austria&apos;, &apos;Belgium&apos;, &apos;China&apos;, &apos;Denmark&apos;, &apos;Finland&apos;, &apos;France&apos;, &apos;Germany&apos;, &apos;Italy&apos;, &apos;Japan&apos;, &apos;Korea&apos;, &apos;Netherlands&apos;, &apos;Singapore&apos;, &apos;Spain&apos;, &apos;Sweden&apos;, &apos;Switzerland&apos;, &apos;United Kingdom&apos;)</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
</report>
```